# Determine the power series of $\sin^2 \cos x$

Tags: power-series

I don't know why I found 2 different answers.
When using the product of the series then the binomial identity

$$\sin^2(x) \cos(x)=\sin(2x)\sin(x/2) $$
I found $$\sin^2(x) \cos(x)=\sum x^2\frac{(-4)^n (9^{n+1}-1)x^{2n}}{(2n+2)!4^{n+1}}.$$
By converting $\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$
into $$\sin^2(x)\cos(x)=(1/4)\cos(x) -(1/4)\cos(3x)$$
I got
$$\sin^2(x) \cos(x)=\frac{1\sum{(-1)^n x^{2n}(1-9)^n}}{4\cdot(2n)!}.$$
Which of them is true?

Comment: do you mean $\sin^2 x \cos x$ or do you mean $\sin^2(\cos x)$

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean
$$\sin^2 x\cos x?$$
This is
$$\frac12\sin x\sin 2x.$$
Using the identity,
$$\sin A\sin B=\frac{\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)}2$$
we get
$$\sin^2 x\cos x=\frac{\cos x-\cos3x}4.$$
Now use $\cos y=\sum_n (-1)^ny^{2n}/(2n)!$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first power series is correct. The second attempt has promise. You have correctly given $\sin(x)^2cos(x)=(1/4)\cos(x)-(1/4)\cos(3x)$ which should give the same answer but you did not expand the two power series correctly. In particular, $(1-9)^n$ should be $(1^n-9^n)$.